# have issue with foundation dropdown menu in top-bar

Tags: javascript, css, django, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I install foundation-sites with yarn or npm. So i have sources in node_modules/foundation-sites. I use django but i have the same issue without it

Here is my index.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% load sass_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>short url</title>
    {% load compress %}
    {% compress css %}
      <link href="{% sass_src 'scss/style.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    {% endcompress %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
          <li class="menu-text">shorturl</li>
          <li><a href="/shorturl">Racine</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shorturl/url_list">url list</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="http://www.perdu.com">perdu</a>
            <ul class="menu vertical">
              <li><a href="#">Lien 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Lien 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

      <script src="{% static "js/jquery/dist/jquery.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/what-input/dist/what-input.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.core.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.dropdown.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.dropdownMenu.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.util.keyboard.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.util.box.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins/foundation.util.nest.js" %}"></script>
      <script src="{% static "js/app.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i load the web-page, i have this:[issue with dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paI17.png)

Someone has an idea to solve it ?

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a mistake in my js/app.js.

I forget () at the end to initialize foundation. So i put this:

```
$(document).foundation();
```